# $I\triangleleft R$ and $I$ nilpotent. $E$ a simple $R$-module. What does $IE$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am trying to do an assignment question, but I'm struggling with notation. It is described in the question, but I can't quite visualise what it means - and it seems as though it's really straightforward!

Let $R$ be a ring, $I\subset R$ a nilpotent ideal and $E$ a simple $R$-module.

I am required to do something with the set $IE$. I know what I need to do, but I do not know what $IE$ means.

Intuitively, I would assume
$$IE=\{ax\mid a\in I, x\in E\}.$$

However, in the question, it is described as follows:

"where $IE$ is the set of all sums of elements $ax$ with $a\in I$ and $x\in E$."

Which is making me think that $IE$ is the following (I'm not sure of the correct notation here...)
$$IE=\left\{\sum ax \mid a\in I, x\in E\right\}.$$

I am trying to prove that this set is a submodule of $E$ - which I am perfectly comfortable with doing and do not need any help with. But I need to know exactly the set I need to check!

Thanks,

Andy.

Comment: The second one is the good one, only add that the sums are finite.

Comment: Thank you @mathma. Is $IE=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i\mid a_i\in I, x_i\in E, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ a better way to write it?

Comment: It must be the second, if you try to prove the first is a submodule, you'll notice it need not be closed under addition. As for notation, I'd write
$$
IE = \left\{\left.\sum_{x\in E}a_x x\,\right| a_x\in I, x\in E,a_x = 0\textrm{ for almost all }x\right\}.
$$
The way you've written it in the comment is also fine.

Comment: @andrew1601 you can express it like that if you want. Although I think that usually the subscript $finite$, or  $a=0$ for all but finitely many $a\in I$ is prefered.

Comment: @andrew1601 What is the rest of the actual question you are working on, out of curiosity?!

Comment: I needed to show that $IE=0$. So I showed that $IE$ is a submodule of $E$, and then $IE=0$ or $IE=E$. But $IE=E\implies I^n E=E$ for all integers $n\geq 1$. However, since $I$ is nilpotent, there exists some integer $k$ such that $I^k=0\implies I^kE=0$. This is a contradiction, so we must have $IE=0$.